Alternative to regular printed circuit board base material that can be cut by hand / with scissors / cutter
I'm currently designing a PCB with components (LEDs, magnets) and holes which require precise locations.
To leverage an iterative physical prototype design process, I'm looking for a board material that can be easily cut and drilled by hand, e.g. by using scissors or box cutters; that is, I want to avoid FR4 material.
The material should be stiff (e.g. no paper sheets) and be able to glue components to.

Does it need to be able to be cut in arbitrary locations, or would perforations in specific locations be good enough?

Pertinax springs to mind.

What about the thinnest easily available FR-4, like 0.4mm? It’s abrasive though and will dull good scissors.

I've seen a kit somewhere that provided metallic ink. You could draw on regular paper to treat it like a circuit board (although resistivity was higher than copper). No reason the same couldn't be done on stiffer paper, wood, or even plastic. You can also upgrade scissors to "tin snips" - sheet metal shears.

Do you actually need a PCB, or could you get away with a non-functional board for experimentation? Have you considered cardboard or polystyrene sheet?

maybe cutting the board material is not the only solution ... what are you trying to build?

@user1937198, I'll go to the arts supply shop today and give it a try

FR2 (phenolic paper),  with enough scraping you can cut it with a box cutter (but a fine tooth saw works much better)  It's basically wood and plastic so it won't dull blades and drills like epoxy fibreglass (FR4) does.
If it doesn't need to be rigid then "flex" (polyimide) can easily be cut using scissors and other common office tools.
If you're not needing copper tracks adhered to the surface then thick cardstock or thin MDF or plywood may be suitable.

Even if you do need copper on the surface, you could use thick card with copper tape, too.
